# Cannot connect to postgresql container using npm pg in a docker-compose scenario

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose, node-postgres

I am using `npm pg` (`"pg": "^7.18.2", "pg-native": "^3.0.0"` in my package.json), at which I am new, to connect my newbie `node` app to a `postgresql` database. I use `docker-compose` to start up everything using this configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres_user"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    depends_on:
      - fibclient
      - fibserver
  fibserver:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - './server:/app'
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - PGUSER=postgres_user
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGPORT=5432
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - fibworker
    ports:
      - '9229:9229'
  fibclient:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - './client:/app'
  fibworker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./fibworker
    volumes:
      - './fibworker:/app'
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    ports:
      - '9230:9229'
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

As you can imagine `fibserver` is the backend app trying to connect to `postgres` service which is hosting the `postgresql` database. Sadly, `fibserver` app is always getting this error while connecting to the database:

```
fibserver_1  | Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
fibserver_1  |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:255:9)
fibserver_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
fibserver_1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
fibserver_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:78:10)
fibserver_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
fibserver_1  |     at emitCloseNT (net.js:1657:8)
fibserver_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21)
fibserver_1  |     at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
fibserver_1  |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:520:9)
fibserver_1  |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:494:7)
```

I double-checked my `docker-compose` file, if services are aware of each other (`fibserver` can ping `postgres`), `npm pg` configuration, docs and examples, and everything looks ok to me. Still missing something. [This](https://github.com/fpezzati/fibsequence) is where you can find the whole stuff.

*UPDATE:*
I put a simple circuit-breaker in my `fibserver`: when he fails to connect to database it wait for a while and tries again. Well, `fibserver` did a lot of attempts to connect do `postgres` service, even after 10 minutes. Could be my usage of `npm pg` library to cause this issue? I also update the master if anyone wants to have a look. Thankyou.

*UPDATE:*
I installed psql into fibserver container and I managed to connect to postgres service succesfully, I think it's a matter of how I am using the pg client. This was something I should have tried before.

Comment: try to use compose v2 and use this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on
maybe it takes time for postgress to initialize. if the depends_on doesn't work try with a health check like here https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck

Comment: @Eitank thanks for the tip, I'll try it a.s.a.p! But, shouldn't postgres service came up before fibserver because of depends-on attribute in docker-compose file?

Comment: `depends_on:` causes the database container to start starting before the application container, but doesn't wait for it to be fully up.  [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) discusses this in more detail.

Comment: @Francesco try the health check

Comment: @Eitank I tried the healthcheck in a 2.1 docker-compose but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally having some time to go further this issue. I uninstall the two `pg` modules in my fibserver application and install pg again provides me a new version of `npm` `pg` module (8.3.3) without having the native part which I probably installed by mistake. Single javascript `pg` library does the job.